# Meaning of "furnished with a pipe and a supply of cold without" in Trollope's "Orley Farm"

Tags: meaning, anthony-trollope, orley-farm

In Trollope's *Orley Farm* we are told that Mr. Moulder was "furnished with a pipe and a supply of cold without." What does this mean? It appears a little later that Moulder also has a glass of brandy and water.

<sub>Trollope, Anthony. *[Orley Farm](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/23000/23000-h/23000-h.htm)*. 1861–1862. [Chapter 6](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/23000/23000-h/23000-h.htm#c6). Retrieved from Project Gutenberg, 20 November 2023.</sub>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Cold without* refers to Mr Moulder's drink: brandy mixed with unsweetened cold water. The Oxford English Dictionary has the following entry for **cold without**:

> *colloquial*.
> Brandy or spirits in cold water without sugar.
>
> <sub>“cold without, n.”. *Oxford English Dictionary*, Oxford University Press, September 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/4686028074. Accessed 29 November 2023.</sub>

The two examples given are from 1850 and 1853. *Orley Farm* was published in monthly installments between 1861 and 1862, so this noun phrase would have been in currency then.